# Using Unix TC to shape high bandwidth traffic

Tags: linux, networking, controls, bandwidth, traffic

We actually have a 10Gb/s servers and 1Gb/s servers that coexist together (temporary migrating solution) [UDP traffic]. We would like to shape the traffic coming from the 10Gb/s servers in order to avoid big bursts that the 1G servers could not handle.

It seems that "tc" cannot do the job with a tbf (or maybe we use it the wrong way). For instance on our 10G servers we tried the following:

sudo tc qdisc add dev eth5 root tbf rate 950mbit latency 1s burst 50mbit peakrate 1000mbit mtu 1500

Here we normally set the peakrate at 1mb (which normally can't generate burst > 1mb/s).
Unfortunately, that does not work, in fact after using this tc config, we lower our main bandwidth to at max 2Mb/s..

Our only clue for this strange behavior is that sentence in the tc manual:

"To achieve perfection, the second bucket may contain only a single packet, which leads to the earlier mentioned 1mbit/s limit.

This limit is caused by the fact that the kernel can only throttle for at minimum 1 'jiffy', which depends on HZ as 1/HZ. For perfect shaping, only a single packet can get sent per jiffy - for HZ=100, this means 100 packets of on average 1000 bytes each, which roughly corresponds to 1mbit/s. "

So, it's sure we can't have a peakrate > 1Mbit/s ?

Maybe, there is another completely different way to achieve our goal, if anyone has a suggestion that would help me achieve our goal.. =) ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a 1s latency? Seems WAY too high for a 1 Gbit link